# Add styling to django Password reset forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to add styling to django's default password reset form such as classes and placeholders

I have the following in my urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [

    # Password reset paths

    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="main/password_reset.html"),name="reset_password"),
    path('password_reset_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="main/password_reset_sent.html"),name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset_password/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="main/reset_password.html"),name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="main/reset_password_complete.html"),name="password_reset_complete"),
]
```

in the templates

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form}}
            <input type="submit" name="Send email" class="btn btn-primary" >
        </form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes of course you can overwrite django forms.

```
# forms.py

from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class UserPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserPasswordResetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    email = forms.EmailField(label='', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'your class',
        'placeholder': 'your placeholder',
        'type': 'email',
        'name': 'email'
        }))

# urls.py

from .forms import UserPasswordResetForm

path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='main/password_reset.html',
    form_class=UserPasswordResetForm),name='password_reset'),
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for , i'll up vote when i try it , thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try Using **django-crispy-forms**.

**Installation**

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Add it to your INSTALLED_APPS and select the style:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'crispy_forms',
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Load the tag

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

Now you can style the form

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

Comment: i found this solution but i'm checking if there is another way that django provides for this purpose without third party stuff , thank you for your answer

Comment: I think you need to load the crispy tags in the template

Comment: I think what @SerioUs pointed out is correct. You can override the Password reset form by updating the widget field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using django-crispy-forms and/or django-widget-tweaks

Answer (score 0):

Use Crispy Forms, here is a well explained article about it
[CrispyForms](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html)